# How to make sql query result to xml file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I have an sql query, selects some data from a table.

```
ID    Name    Number    Email
1      a        123       a@a.com
2      b        321       b@b.com
3      c        432       c@c.com
```

I get these datas from the table. I want create a xml file from the data. Like this

```
<Students>
  <Student>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>a</name>
      <number>123</number>
      <email>a@a.com</email>
  </Student>
  <Student>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>b</name>
      <number>321</number>
      <email>b@b.com</email>
  </Student>
  <Student>
      <id>3</id>
      <name>c</name>
      <number>432</number>
      <email>c@c.com</email>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

How can I do it on C# and SQL Server ?

Comment: you want to create xml file or structure like xml

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourStudentTable
FOR XML PATH('Student'), ROOT ('Students')
```

This should return exactly the XML you're looking for (*assuming* you have SQL Server **2005** or newer)

Read [more about how to use `FOR XML PATH` and its capabilities on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx)

Comment: I didn't know that. That pretty much made my year. You have my thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**SQL Server**:
just an addition to [@marc_s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18654213/1744834) - note that xml is case-sensitive, and resulting xml will look like

```
<Students>
   <Student>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>a</Name>
      <Number>123</Number>
      <Email>a@a.com</Email>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

and if you'll try to retrieve `id`, you'll not find anything.

you may want to do something like this:

```
select
    ID as id,
    Name as name,
    Number as number,
    Email as email
from dbo.Table1
for xml path('Student'), root('Students')
```

[**=> sql fiddle example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ada01/4).

**C#**:
you can use [WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) method:

```
var ds = new DataSet("Students");
var dt = ds.Tables.Add("Student");
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("number", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("email", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(1, "a", "123", "a@a.com");
dt.Tables[0].Rows.Add(2, "b", "321", "b@b.com");
dt.Tables[0].Rows.Add(3, "c", "432", "c@c.com");
var stream = new StringWriter();
ds.WriteXml(stream);
```

or using Linq to XML:

```
 new XElement("Students", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>
       new XElement("Student",
            new XElement("id", r["id"]),
            new XElement("name", r["name"]),
            new XElement("number", r["number"]),
            new XElement("email", r["email"])
       )));
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Create class called student

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Number { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

2) Get data into List called `StudentList`from Database

3)Then open or create xml file and add values

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Student.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Students");

    foreach (Student student in StudentList)
    {
    writer.WriteStartElement("Student");

    writer.WriteElementString("id", student.ID.ToString());
    writer.WriteElementString("name", student.Name.ToString());
    writer.WriteElementString("number", student.Number.ToString());
    writer.WriteElementString("email", student.Email.ToString());

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataSet.GetXml()` function for getting result in XML format file

Answer (score 1):

Though the solution provided by marc is exactly what you need, you may want to have a deeper look at various options in the article [Using the FOR XML Clause to Return Query Results as XML](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-the-for-xml-clause-to-return-query-results-as-xml/).