# How to save SQL query result to XML file on disk

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I would like to export table from SQL Server 2012 to XML file. I have found [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654157/how-to-make-sql-query-result-to-xml-file) and [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-the-for-xml-clause-to-return-query-results-as-xml/) how to make XML result from SQL Server database query, but still I am missing how to save this result physically into file.

SQL query is:

```
SELECT [Created], [Text]
FROM [db304].[dbo].[SearchHistory]
FOR XML PATH('Record'), ROOT('SearchHistory')
```

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to execute this result. I see the XML in a result window, but I cannot save it.

There is "Save Result As.." in context menu, but with 98900 rows I run out of my 8GB memory with this option.

Is there a way how to save this query directly to the XML file on disk?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also your SQL Server's extended stored procedures to export it to an xml file.

But you would need to configure the sql server before you can use it.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
```

Once xp_cmdshel is enabled in the SQL Server. You can use the following command to export the data to an xml file.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT [Created], [Text] FROM [db304].[dbo].[SearchHistory] FOR XML PATH(''Record''), ROOT(''SearchHistory'')" queryout "C:\bcptest.xml" -T -c -t,'
```

Comment: Thanks, I can export entire table, but I cannot get work UTF-8.  When I use -C65001 parameter, I get message Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]This version of SQL Server Native Client does not support UTF-8 encoding (code page 65001). I will need to upgrade to SQL Server 2016, there is already support for UTF8 for this feature.

Comment: Hello, this is just what I was looking for. Please explain what the bcp is for "EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT [Created]," Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can always use the "Results to File" option in SSMS:

[image]

That should output the results of the query execution directly into a file on disk

Comment: That is what I was looking for, but unfortunately the file is cropped, the end of the file is missing. :-( The XML is interrupted inside the element. But SSMS sais: "Query executed successfully".

Comment: @qub1n: that's unfortunate..... in that case, I guess my only alternative would be to write a little C# program to run the query, get the results, and try to save them to disk - possibly do it in chunks (e.g. 1000 rows at a time or so) to avoid the "OutOfMemoryException" ...

Comment: If there is a large content like a large xml file, only a part of the file is written.

Answer (score 2):

To this job in SQL Server 2012 is a pain in ass. Finally I end up to update it to SQL Server 2014 as there is already support for SQL UTF-8 files in sqlcmd.

1. Create an SQL query and save it to the file.
2. run following:

   sqlcmd -S  -U sa -P sapassword -i inputquery_file_name -C65001 -o outputfile_name

Comment: For me, it was necessary to add the `-y 0` option to make sure the entire XML was exported, not just the first 256 characters.

Answer (score 2):

This example works for me for result sets up to 2GB in size.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##AuditLogTempTable

SELECT A.MyXML
INTO ##AuditLogTempTable
FROM
(SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), 
    (
            SELECT
                A.*
            FROM
                [dbo].[AuditLog] A
                JOIN ImportProviderProcesses IPP ON IPP.ImportType = 'Z' 
                  AND A.OperatorID = IPP.OperatorID 
                  AND A.AuditTypeID in ( '400','424','425' )
            WHERE
                A.[PostTime] >= IPP.StartTime
                AND A.[PostTime] <= dateadd(second, 90, IPP.StartTime) 
                FOR XML PATH('Record'), ROOT('AuditLog')
        )
    , 0
    )   AS MyXML
) A

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT MyXML FROM ##AuditLogTempTable" queryout "D:\bcptest1.xml" -T -c -t,'
```