# Read BLOB column and convert it to xml in a file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a  column that is a blob. Here is the screenshot:

[image: TBDocuments table with Document Column As BLOB]

As you can see that I have a `TBDOCUMENTS` table. In this table `DOCUMENT` column is `BLOB`. I want to read this column. Then I know that for this particular `DOCUMENTURL` this column contains xml. So I want to convert it into XML. And then I want to write this XML in a file.

How can I do it in SQL Server? I am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the xml you stored inside a blob column (for example `varbinary`) you can use `CONVERT`:

```
select CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),DOCUMENT))) 
from TBDOCUMENTS
where DOCUMENTURL='...'
```

Now you can write this string to an XML file. I think that SQL Server is probably not a good fit for this task; nonetheless there are many techniques to achieve this, for example with bcp (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#bulk_export_xml_data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808738/909742))

As reported in the comments a DTD related error may occur when using `CONVERT`:

> Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use CONVERT with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support.

In this case using the xml-styles option of `CONVERT` command (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#xml-styles)) fixes the problem:

```
select CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),DOCUMENT)), 2)
from TBDOCUMENTS
where DOCUMENTURL='...'
```

Comment: Thanks. After running the query I got this error `Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use CONVERT with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support.` So I used `select CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),DOCUMENT)), 2) ` And it worked. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Basit thank you for your comment: I edited my answer including your considerations to help other users in the future