# Save data for SQL Server to XML file

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net

I have a project in VB and a function that returns data from SQL Server. The data is saved in a variable. I need to insert the data directly to XML file.

I need vb. code/ script that will save the data to a XML file.

How can I save data from a table in SQL Server into a XML file?

Can anyone send me code to save data from SQL Server to XML file in VB, I have never done this before and I don' have any ideas how to do it.

[It should be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc6Ed.png) 
The problem is that I don't know how to write " `-<CON xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`" at the beginning of the file

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save SQL query result to XML file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808516/how-to-save-sql-query-result-to-xml-file-on-disk)

Comment: Time to learn XML programming then, is it not? Having other people do your work is helping you how?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I save data from table SQL Server to XML file.

Simple: Programming. Grab the data, write the XML file. THere really is no sensible support in SQL Server to write a XML file - among other things because you would write it ON THE SERVER.

Comment: _"...write it ON THE SERVER"_ That is not entirely correct. The file location must be accessible to the service account but it does not need to be on the same machine.

Comment: Exactly. ON THE SERVER - it saves it on the server, under the identity of the service. Wherever you go from there - so yes, you can save it i.e. on a file share, but most people seem to think (question comes up often) that it saves on the client. Nope.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to XML API is very easy to use.

**VB.Net**

```
Private Sub Main()
    Const fileName As String = "e:\temp\fileName.xml"
    Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse("<root>text</root>")
    xdoc.Save(fileName)
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to write ` -<CON xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">` at the beginning of the file

Comment: @kvacka, you need to create a new post for your new question.

Comment: Why should I create new post ?

Comment: Because this is a different question. One question, one post.