# How to query form a parent and child table and return the result as XML?

Tags: sql

I have two tables Customer and Order

customer Table has customerId, CustomerName

Order Table has OrderId, CustomerId, ProductId

the result i want is an xml file

```
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>7</CustomerId>
    <CustomerName>def</CustomerName>
    <Orders>
      <Customerorder>
          <OrderId>5</OrderId>
          <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
          <ProductId>3</ProductId>
      </Customerorder>
      <Customerorder>
          <OrderId>5</OrderId>
          <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
          <ProductId>3</ProductId>
      </Customerorder>
    </Orders>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
        <CustomerId>2</CustomerId>
        <CustomerName>abc</CustomerName>
        <Orders>
            <Customerorder>
                <OrderId>5</OrderId>
                <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
                <ProductId>3</ProductId>
            </Customerorder>
            <Customerorder>
                <OrderId>5</OrderId>
                <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
                <ProductId>3</ProductId>
            </Customerorder>
        </Orders>
    </Customer>
 </Customers>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654157/how-to-make-sql-query-result-to-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

you have error data in xml such as id 1 and id 7.

is it what you need?

```
declare @Customer Table(CustomerID int, CustomerName varchar(50))
insert into @Customer(CustomerID, CustomerName)
Values
(1, 'def'), (2, 'abc')
select * from @Customer

declare @Order Table(OrderID int, CustomerID int, ProductID int)
insert into @Order(OrderID, CustomerID, ProductID)
Values
(5,1, 3), (6,1,4),
(4,2,4),(5,2,6)
select * from @Order


select 
      c.CustomerID
    , c.CustomerName
    , (select  
        (SELECT * FROM @Order o 
            WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
            FOR XML PATH('CustomerOrder'), type)
      FOR XML PATH ('Orders'), type)
From @Customer c
FOR XML PATH('Customer'), ROOT ('Customers')
```

[image]